# Moving chars in String while ignore Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I need to create method in which the input will be string for example: asd321tre2.
The output should be: eas321dtr2. The chars should be moved forward for one position but the numbers should stay on the same position.
Input : String s1 = "abc23sd23";
Output: String s2 = "dab23cs23";

```
public static String revertTheString (String s) {
    String helper = s.replaceAll("\\d", "");
    helper = helper.substring(helper.length()-1) + helper.substring(0, helper.length()-1);
    int start = 0, end = 0;

    StringBuilder revert = new StringBuilder(s);

    for (int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
            end = i;
            revert = revert.replace(start, end, helper.substring(start, end));
            while(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
                i++;
                start = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return revert.toString();
}
```

Comment: show us your code pls

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try swaping first and last char value like below.

===========================================

```
    String s = "asd321tre2";
    char[] charr = s.toCharArray();
    int end = 0;

    for (int i = s.length(); i <= 0; i--) {
        if (Character.isLetter(charr[i])) {
            end = i;

        }
    }
    String output = charReplace(end, charr);
}

private static String charReplace(int end, char[] ch) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch[i])) {
            char tmp = ch[i];
            ch[i] = ch[end];
            ch[end] = tmp;
        }
    }
    String output = String.valueOf(ch);
    return output;

}
```

===========================================

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Parthiban